# javascript SaveAs for Excel

Tags: javascript, excel

I have the following:

```
var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
oWin.document.write(strExcelHtml);
oWin.document.close();
var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', false, fileName)
oWin.close();
```

When the save window comes up, I want to see .xls as the "Save As" type. How do I do this?

Comment: try reading this - http://eligrey.com/blog/post/saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side/